# Checking if np.nan is inside an array returns non expected values

Tags: python, numpy

Why an array element `arr[i][j]` when equal to `nan`, is not being validated as np.nan?

I have ran some tests with the variable and was not able to found why that is hapenning.

```
In : nval
Out: array([  0.,  nan])

In : type(nval)
Out: numpy.ndarray

In : type(nval[0])
Out: numpy.float64

In : type(nval[1])
Out: numpy.float64

In : arr[15][4] 
Out: nan

In : type(arr[15][4])
Out: numpy.float64
# Expected True
In : arr[15][4] == np.nan
Out: False

# Expected True
In:  nval[1] == np.nan
Out: False

# Expected True    
In:  arr[15][4] == nval[1]
Out: False

# Expected True
In:  arr[15][4] in nval
Out: False

In:  0 in nval
Out: True

# Expected True    
In:  np.nan in nval
Out: False
```

I think all are failing by the same reason, just can't figure out where.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def spill(arr, nval=[0,np.nan], metric=1):
    m=metric
    narr=np.copy(arr)
    nval=np.asarray(nval)
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
            if arr[i][j] not in nval:
                # This helps to check what is happening
                # print "{0},{1}: {2}".format(i,j,arr[i][j])
                # print narr[i-m:i+m+1:1,j-m:j+m+1:1]
                narr[i-m:i+m+1:1,j-m:j+m+1:1]=arr[i][j]                    
    return narr


msize=50
rrange=10
jump=10
start=5
dpi=96
h=500
w=500

X,Y=np.meshgrid(range(0,msize),range(0,msize))
dat=np.random.rand(msize,msize)*rrange


msk=np.zeros_like(dat)
msk[start::jump,start::jump].fill(1)
mdat=msk*dat
mdat[mdat==0]=np.nan

# If I run spill over the `mdat` before the np.nan, all works fine
# as expected by the tests above. But I wish to be able to check
# also against `np.nan`.
sdat = spill(mdat)

mmdat = ma.masked_where(np.isnan(mdat),mdat)
smdat = ma.masked_where(np.isnan(sdat),sdat)

print mmdat[5]
# I expected similar output except smdat[5][4] and smdat[5][6] should
# be equal to smdat[5][5].
print smdat[5]
```

Comment: Test for `nan` with  `x is np.nan` not `x==np.nan`.  It is like the Python `None`.

Comment: `arr[15][4] is np.nan` returns `False` (but `arr[15[4]` is np.nan, at least I think so)

Comment: It is better to index 2d arrays with `arr[15,4]` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `np.isnan` according to [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html)

Comment: To add to that, ``NaN != NaN`` according to IEEE 754 standard, and ``numpy`` conforms to it.

Comment: @fjarri Sorry but I did not understand what do you mean

Comment: `np.isnan(arr[15][4])` returns `True`, good. But how can I check this against the input array `nval` since  the `in` operator isn't usable?

Comment: @fjarri: I still do not understand. Imagine that nval = np.array([0, np.nan]). If you try to use np.isnan(nval) you will get [False  True] according to documentation.

Comment: I have used: `if (not np.isnan(arr[i][j])) and (arr[i][j]  not in nval): ...` therefore isnan will always be considered a value to be ignored.

Comment: @gelezko: `isnan` is not the same as `== nan`. See e.g. OP's attempt to evaluate `arr[15][4] == np.nan`. Even though `arr[15][4]` *is* `nan`, it still is not equal to `nan`. It goes all the way down to the machine code level, where comparing `NaN` and `NaN` will result in a false value, as per IEEE 754.